# Rails on production server not logging anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When my rails app encounters an internal server error, it serves up a 500 page as you it should, but it outputs nothing to the log file.

Quite literally, my entire production.log file is as follows:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Migrating to CreateStates (20130221172503)
Migrating to CreateCarriers (20130225200710)
Migrating to DeviseCreateUsers (20130226212033)
Migrating to CreateAccounts (20130226221603)
Migrating to CreateAccountsUsers (20130226221735)
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

Can anyone help me diagnose this? I'm running Apache and Passenger, as usual, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.12.

Comment: You aren't running in development mode or anything, are you?

Comment: I specify a production environment in both my Capistrano deploy file and my Apache http-vhosts.conf file. What's more, production.log is the only file in my logs directory.

Comment: I assume your application in development environment correctly produces logs? Can you paste your environment/production.rb file (kindly remove all comment lines, and mask sensitive information such as password)

Comment: Here's my production.rb file: http://pastie.org/6481600

Comment: Yes, it does log correctly in development. (I have just tested.)

Comment: I don't see anything fancy in your environment file, perhaps it's a user right matter. Just try to give full access to all users to your log directory (and files in it) and restart your server. If the log file start to fill up then you should investigate that way (ex: with which user your web server runs, etc...) don't forget to secure your log directory once you are done

Comment: I changed the permissions to `777`, but that produced no better effect.

Comment: Are you logging things using `puts` or `Rails.logger.log`?

Comment: What about the apache log? Maybe is logging something about that.

Comment: @Alter, I checked. Nothing but access.

Comment: @drewinglis, I was calling `logger.info "fdsafsda"` from within the controller action. (Now it occurs to me that that function was probably below the log level, but earlier, I was getting a 500 error, and still had nothing showing up in the log.)

Comment: @JellicleCat According to the production.rb file you linked, your log level was DEBUG, so INFO-level messages should be showing up in the logs. Do you know if the `logger.info "blah"` code was executing successfully? And I take it that wasn't showing up in the logs either?

Comment: @drewlinglis, that is correct: it was not showing up in the logs.

Comment: For some reason, the logs are working today. I can't guess why. I restarted the rails server and Apache multiple times yesterday to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Apache global error log. Phusion Passenger redirects processes' stderr to that file.